# sudo apt-get upgrade sudo apt-get install not working after upgrading Python

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, package-management, python

I recently updated Python 2.7.6 to Python 2.7.12. Since then, when I run `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get install` or `apt-get autoremove` I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-xapian-index : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 caribou : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 duplicity : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 gconf2 : Depends: python:any
 gimp : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ipython : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ipython-notebook : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 jackd2 : Depends: python:any
 libgcj-common : Depends: python:any
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 mintstick : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 mintupdate : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 nemo-emblems : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                Depends: python:any (>= 2.7~)
 pylint : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-all : Depends: python (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but 2.7.12-1 is installed
 python-all-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but 2.7.12-1 is installed
 python-apt : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-aptdaemon : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-astroid : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-bs4 : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-cairo : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-chardet : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-colorama : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-commandnotfound : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-configglue : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-configobj : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-crypto : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-cupshelpers : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-dateutil : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-dbus : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-debian : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-debtagshw : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-decorator : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-defer : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but 2.7.12-1 is installed
 python-dirspec : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-distlib : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                  Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-dnspython : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-docutils : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-feedparser : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-gi : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-gnome2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-gobject-2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-gtk2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-html5lib : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-httplib2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-imaging : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-jinja2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-kivy : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
               Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-kivy-common : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                      Depends: python:any (>= 2.7~)
 python-ldb : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-libxml2 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-lockfile : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-logilab-common : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                         Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-lxml : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-mako : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-markupsafe : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-notify : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-numpy : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-oauthlib : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                   Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-oneconf : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-opencv : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-opengl : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                 Depends: python-ctypes
 python-openssl : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-paramiko : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pexpect : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pil : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pip : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
              Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-piston-mini-client : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pkg-resources : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7)
                        Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-protobuf : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-pyatspi : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pycurl : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pygame : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pygments : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pyinotify : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pyparsing : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pyrex : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-pyside.qtcore : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-qt4 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-reportlab : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-requests : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-roman : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-samba : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-scipy : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-serial : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-setuptools : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7)
                     Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-sip : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-six : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
              Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-skimage : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-smbc : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-tdb : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-tornado : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-twisted-core : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-twisted-names : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-twisted-web : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-tz : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-ubuntu-sso-client : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-urllib3 : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                  Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
 python-utidylib : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-webkit : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-xapian : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-xdg : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 python-zmq : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
 python-zope.interface : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 sessioninstaller : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 totem : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 totem-plugins : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 ubuntu-system-service : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
 virtualbox : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Then if I run `apt-get -f install`, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  docutils-common fonts-font-awesome fonts-mathjax freeglut3 gir1.2-gtk-2.0
  gist ipython-notebook-common libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev
  libavresample-dev libavutil-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2
  libdc1394-22-dev libfreeimage3 libgsoap4 libharfbuzz-dev
  libharfbuzz-gobject0 libilmbase-dev libjasper-dev libjbig-dev
  libjs-highlight libjs-jquery-ui libjs-marked libjs-mathjax liblzma-dev
  libopencv-calib3d-dev libopencv-core-dev libopencv-features2d-dev
  libopencv-flann-dev libopencv-gpu-dev libopencv-gpu2.4 libopencv-imgproc-dev
  libopencv-ml-dev libopencv-ocl2.4 libopencv-photo-dev
  libopencv-stitching-dev libopencv-stitching2.4 libopencv-superres2.4
  libopencv-ts-dev libopencv-ts2.4 libopencv-video-dev libopencv-videostab2.4
  libopencv2.4-java libopencv2.4-jni libopenexr-dev libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0
  libpixman-1-dev libportmidi0 libpyside1.2 libpython-all-dev
  libpython-stdlib:i386 libpython2.7-minimal:i386 libpython2.7-stdlib:i386
  libraw1394-dev libraw9 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0
  libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 libshiboken1.2 libsmpeg0 libswscale-dev libtiff5-dev
  libtiffxx5 libvncserver0 libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev
  libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev
  libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev python-chardet-whl python-colorama-whl
  python-distlib-whl python-html5lib-whl python-matplotlib-data python-pip-whl
  python-requests-whl python-setuptools-whl python-simplegeneric
  python-six-whl python-urllib3-whl ruby-json x11proto-composite-dev
  x11proto-damage-dev x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-randr-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev xclip xsel
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libsmbclient libutempter0 samba-common samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs
  samba-vfs-modules smbclient xterm
Suggested packages:
  heimdal-clients xfonts-cyrillic
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt-xapian-index apturl apturl-common caribou cinnamon cinnamon-bluetooth
  cinnamon-control-center cinnamon-desktop-data cinnamon-screensaver
  cinnamon-session cinnamon-settings-daemon duplicity gcalcli gconf2 gdebi
  gedit gimp gir1.2-cinnamondesktop-3.0 gir1.2-muffin-3.0 gksu gnome-terminal
  gnome-terminal-data gstreamer0.10-gconf gstreamer0.10-gnomevfs
  gtk-recordmydesktop guake ipython ipython-notebook jackd2 libatk1.0-dev
  libbonoboui2-0 libcairo2-dev libcinnamon-desktop4 libcv-dev libcvaux-dev
  libgcj-common libgcj14 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgksu2-0 libglib2.0-dev
  libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnome2-perl libgnome2-vfs-perl
  libgnomeui-0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra
  libgtk2.0-dev libhighgui-dev libopencv-contrib-dev libopencv-dev
  libopencv-highgui-dev libopencv-legacy-dev libopencv-objdetect-dev
  libopencv-ocl-dev libopencv-superres-dev libopencv-videostab-dev
  libpango1.0-dev libpurple-bin libreoffice-gnome mdm mint-artwork-common
  mint-artwork-gnome mint-common mint-meta-cinnamon mint-meta-codecs
  mint-meta-core mintbackup mintdrivers mintinstall mintnanny mintsources
  mintstick mintsystem mintupdate mintupload mintwelcome nemo nemo-emblems
  nemo-fileroller nemo-folder-color-switcher nemo-preview nemo-share
  oneconf-common pdftk pylint python-all python-all-dev python-apt
  python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-astroid python-bs4
  python-cairo python-chardet python-colorama python-commandnotfound
  python-configglue python-configobj python-crypto python-cupshelpers
  python-dateutil python-dbus python-debian python-debtagshw python-decorator
  python-defer python-dev python-dirspec python-distlib python-dnspython
  python-docutils python-feedparser python-gconf python-gdata python-gi
  python-gi-cairo python-glade2 python-gnome2 python-gnomekeyring
  python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-gtksourceview2
  python-html5lib python-httplib2 python-imaging python-imaging-compat
  python-jinja2 python-kivy python-kivy-bin python-kivy-common python-ldb
  python-libxml2 python-lockfile python-logilab-common python-lxml python-mako
  python-markupsafe python-matplotlib python-nemo python-notify python-numpy
  python-oauthlib python-oneconf python-opencv python-opengl python-openssl
  python-paramiko python-pexpect python-pil python-pip
  python-piston-mini-client python-pkg-resources python-protobuf
  python-pyatspi python-pyatspi2 python-pycurl python-pygame python-pygments
  python-pyinotify python-pyparsing python-pyrex python-pyside.qtcore
  python-pyside.qtgui python-pyside.qtopengl python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus
  python-qt4-gl python-reportlab python-requests python-roman python-samba
  python-scipy python-serial python-setuptools python-sexy python-sip
  python-six python-skimage python-skimage-lib python-smbc python-tdb
  python-tornado python-twisted-core python-twisted-names python-twisted-web
  python-tz python-ubuntu-sso-client python-urllib3 python-utidylib python-vte
  python-webkit python-xapian python-xdg python-zmq python-zope.interface
  python3-oneconf samba samba-common-bin sessioninstaller
  system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome
  system-config-printer-udev tomboy totem totem-mozilla totem-plugins
  totem-plugins-extra transmission-gtk ubuntu-system-adjustments
  ubuntu-system-service virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libutempter0 xterm
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libsmbclient samba-common samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules
  smbclient
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  mintsources python-gtk2 (due to mintsources) python-glade2 (due to
  mintsources) python-pycurl (due to mintsources)
6 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 217 to remove and 65 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,753 kB of archives.
After this operation, 514 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

Moreover, if I `import` any package/module, say, `import numpy`, I get the error:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

The issue I'm sure is with the upgrade. Though Python upgraded to version 2.7.12, links seem to be broken.

I would really appreciate some help, as without `apt-get`, I cannot install new packages, nor upgrade old ones.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you upgrade your python?

Comment: **2nd**: How can you say you're not able to install the packages. It seems that `sudo apt-get install -f` actually removed a lot of packages. **3rd**: What does `python --version` give you? You would not have followed correct way to upgrade python.